# The Error "instantiatedGenerator.run is not a function" Occurs when Generating the Angular Widget use yo angular-js

Tags: node.js, angular, liferay-7

I use

- liferay-ce-portal-7.4.3.14-ga14
- nodejs v20.11.0
- npm 10.4.0
- yo v5.0.0
- generator-liferay-js@2.31.2
  I try also the nodejs v18.17.1 and npm 6.14.12
  I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-frontend-projects/blob/master/maintenance/projects/js-toolkit/docs/How-to-use-generator-liferay-js.md) , get Error "instantiatedGenerator.run is not a function".
  here is my installing steps:
  [installing step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbFgZ.png)

I trying to create UI in liferay portal. Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to version 4.3.1 worked for me. There might be a fix for this in the future. Please watch this issue to stay updated: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator/issues/258